# Difference between infrared heating tube coatings?

Tags: infrared, heat, reflow

I'm converting a toaster oven to a SMD reflow oven and have found the thermal momentum of the resistive elements to be a problem (standard dark-grey type).

So I've been searching online for some cheap IR replacements that I can retrofit. I founds heaps of options including coatings.

What is the difference between clear, ruby, and gold plated tubes? I understand that clear (actually a milky-white) are commonly found in ovens, I read that ruby are 'low glare', and also hear these three types referred to as 'long wave', 'medium wave', and 'short wave'.

Does the coating change the heating/output in anyway? Is it just cosmetic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty, I did some digging around and found some information. Briefly...

## Tube coating/reflectors

Applied directly to the quartz tube (reflectors often only coated on top-half to radiate heat from bottom-half.

- **Clear** - No coating, spreads heat evenly, high temperature.
- **White** - High temperature applications, Moderate reflection.
- **Gold** - Very effective reflection for directional heating, lower temperature.
- **Ruby** - Filters visible light while maintaining IR output (doesn't reflect).

## Wavelength

Specifies the range in the IR portion of the electro-magnetic spectrum.

- **Short/Near** - Doesn't physically feel hot i.e. TV remote.
- **Long/Far** - Physically feels hot, like sun light.
- **Medium/Mid** - A mix of the two depending on how the spectrum is divided.

## Resources

[Helios Italquartz s.r.l.](http://www.heliositalquartz.com/infrared_lamp_literature_158.html) have some good literature on IR quartz heating. They describe these coatings as reflectors:

> 1. GOLD REFLECTOR is a gold layer, fixed directly on the quartz tube. It’s able to reflect more than 90% of IR radiation and if properly
>    cooled it can reach the working temperature of about 600°C;
> 2. WHITE REFLECTOR is a with ceramic layer, fixed directly on the quartz tube. It’s able to reflect about the 70% of IR radiation, so it
>    is less effective compared to the gold one , but it can resist up to a
>    working temperature of about 900 - 1000°C;
> 3. RUBY REFLECTOR is used to mitigate the IR radiation intensity of the filament. It is usually fixed all over the quartz tube in
>    combination with another reflector;

I also found a data-sheet (PDF) by [Osram Halotherm Infrared Lamps](http://www.osram.com.au/media/resource/hires/335362/halotherm-infrared-lamps.pdf)

They describe the intended use for their ruby products:

> Lamps made of ruby quartz predominately emit infra-red heat radiation
> with reduced transmission of visible light. They are used where
> typically visible light would interfere, or in applications where only
> heating is required, e.g. outdoor and indoor zone or space heating and
> auto/marine service or repair shops for drying/curing paint.

Finally, [HowStuffWorks "How Infrared Grills Work"](http://home.howstuffworks.com/infrared-grill.htm)

Describe the infrared spectrum well (page 2), and heating by radiation vs convection (page 3).